# Although users exist in /etc/passwd, but only one of them able to login

Tags: linux, embedded, authentication, busybox

Output from `/etc/passwd`

```
admin:VyaVORqi23kjg:0:0:Administrator:/:/bin/sh
user1:VyaVORqi23kjg:0:0:User1:/:/bin/sh
user:VyaVORqi23kjg:0:0:User:/:/bin/sh
nobody:p/hyihIrG/5hM:0:0:nobody for ftp:/:/bin/sh
```

Output from: `/etc/group`

```
root::0:root,admin,user,user1
```

The problem is "admin" user can login via telnet and ftp and "user" user can only login via ftp and "user1" can not login via both of these. I want to ask why admin is having access to all login channels and "user" to jxt ftp and "user1" to none of these.
Now the question is
Why???
Why this is so?

Comment: What implemetations of `telnetd` and `ftpd` do you have? Are there some restrictions in configuration files? Btw., if what you posted is the actual output of `/etc/passwd`, this is not what one should do - UID 0 is reserved for `root`and '/' should not be the home of any user...

Comment: Note that you should change your passwords after having posted their hash here.

Comment: You are right uid is reserved for root...but this implementation is actual copy slightly modified for DES hashes of password.

Comment: And you can also see from /etc/group that all the user are in root group too

Comment: @Pelletier hashes are not actual one already modified those

Comment: I have a feeling you are not showing us accurate information (copy error).  You should show us your exact configuration and later change the passwords.  Irrelevant spaces and missing information is a real problem.  **exact copy please**

Comment: Are that the actual file contents? There are spaces where there should be none.

Comment: We're actually still missing much critical information such as what ridgy asked at first.  It would probably be useful to also see your `selinux` and `pam` configurations.

Comment: Guys these are actual content..since while posting the question I was accessing the system through android, copy and paste errors occured

Comment: @Julie no selinux, pam support available thus no configuration files

Comment: It seems this implementation is compiled without pam and selinux support

Comment: And configuration files are not at standard locations...causing further trouble

Comment: Please add to your question the type of embedded system this is from (or if it's custom, the Linux build you're using as your starting point).

Comment: Its busybox kernel version 2.6 custom compiled but not by me...running over an IOT device more clearly a refrigerator.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error messages are you getting? It looks like user and user1 have a space at the beginning of the password field that could cause problems. You didn't say what Linux distro you are using. It is possible not having user1 in the root entry in /etc/group could also be a problem.

Comment: Its Busybox linux modified for some embedded device

Comment: Talking about error msg...its invalid user name or password

Comment: User1 is present in /etc/group I missed while copying...now edited

Comment: If the spaces are really at the beginning of the passwd field for user and user1 you should remove them.

Comment: There are no spaces...I know spaces can cause issues in matching hashes..this is not the issue

Comment: @Denzi:  How can you expect us to find your error if you can't show us your configuration without 5 copy errors?